# Prove that (A-B) - C ⊆ A - C

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I came up with a proof but I’m not sure if I’ve done it well. Specifically I’m not sure if number 6 is a valid argument. 
Here it is.
proof: 
Let x ∈ (A-B)-C
1. (A-B)-C = {x|x ∈ (A-B) ∧ x ∉ C} By definition of difference of sets
2. = {x|(x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ B) ∧ x ∉ C}  By definition of difference of sets
3. ={x| x ∉ C ∧ (x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ B) } By commutative laws 
4. = {x| (x ∉ C ∧ x ∈ A) ∧ (x ∉ B ∧ x ∉ B) } distrib. laws of L.E 
5. =  {x| (x ∉ C ∧ x ∈ A) ∧ ¬(x ∈ B v x ∈ B) }Demorgan’s first law of L.E
6. = {x| (x ∉ C ∧ x ∈ A) ∧ T } By 2. x ∉ B and x ∉ B
7. = {x| (x ∉ C ∧ x ∈ A)} By Identity laws of logical equivalence
8. = {x| ( x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ C )} By commutative laws
9. = {x|x ∈ (A-C)} By definition of difference of sets
10. = x ∈ (A-C) meaning of set builder notation
Since  x ∈ (A-B)-C and x ∈ (A-C), then (A-B)-C is a subset of (A-C)
Q.E.D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confused yourself trying to apply distribution in line 4.   There's no need to distribute $\wedge$ over $\wedge$.   Just use commutation and association.

You tried to force every step to be an equality; some need not be, since you are trying to prove the LHS is a subset of the RHS.

Here's a more compact summary of what you need.

$\begin{align}(A-B)-C~=~&\{x\mid (x\in A\wedge x\notin B)\wedge x\notin C\} &&\text{definition of set difference} \\=~& \{x\mid (x\in A\wedge x\notin C)\wedge x\notin B\} && \text{commutation and association over }\wedge\\~=~& (A-C)-B &&\text{definition of set difference}\\ ~\subseteq~& (A-C)&&\text{property of set difference}\end{align}$

Comment: Thank you that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

Since $x\in A-B$ we have $x\in A\land x\not\in B$ so $x\in A$. Since $x\in (A-B)-C$ we have $x\in (A-B) \land x\not\in C$ so $x\not\in C$. By definition $x\in A-C$, so the subset relation is proved.

Answer (score 0):

Hint (where $\overline X$ denotes the [absolute complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Absolute_complement) of $X$): $$(A \setminus B) \setminus C = (A \cap \overline B)\cap \overline C = (A \cap \overline C)\cap \overline B \;\;\subseteq\;\; A \cap \overline C = A \setminus C$$

Answer (score 0):

(A-B)is the set of elements that are in A but not in B
(A−C) is the set of elements in A but not in C
(A−B)−C is the set of elements that are in (A−B) but not in C. Note that if an element is in (A−B) it is in A.

So if an element is in (A−B)−C) it is in A but not in C. therefore it is an element of (A−C) this proves the statement.